# What is the conversation-beginning version of "good night"?

Tags: phrases

Is good evening used at the beginning of conversation, and good night at the end?
what would you use for beginning version of "good night"?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, good evening is used at the beginning of a conversation while good night is used at the conclusion. "Good Evening" has a rising inflection, while "Good Night" has a falling inflection, as it is technically a short form of "Have a Good Night", which is a farewell.

In order to use "Good Night" as a greeting, you will have to change its inflection. For example, you could phrase it as a question: "Good Night, isn't it?". That would be acceptable. However, in the general way of use, there is no specific word that would replace "Good Night".

This likely arises from the fact that most such conversations would begin in the early or late evening, and would end later at night. It would be rare that there would be a gathering at the actual time of night.